# esp32dev kitv1 facing port related errors

Tags: iot, esp32

i have bought the esp32 devkit v1 and when i am trying to upload code to the board it shows
Sketch uses 273093 bytes (20%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Global variables use 21544 bytes (6%) of dynamic memory, leaving 306136 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
esptool.py v4.5.1
Serial port COM5

A fatal error occurred: Could not open COM5, the port doesn't exist
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 2
and in my ide
THE PORT cant be selected i dont know why can you help me

i tryed to install the usb driver pakages for the board and still it does not work

Comment: Could you please give some more information about which IDE you are using and what you are trying to upload?

Answer (score 0):

Try reconnecting the USB cable.

Before you upload, hold down both the BOOT and EN buttons. Release the EN button and you should see a message similar to this:

" rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x3 (DOWNLOAD_BOOT(UART0/UART1/SDIO_REI_REO_V2))

waiting for download "

Then release the BOOT button and try to upload.